# Extra process id from R system("pgrep -f ...") call

Tags: r, procps

When calling `system` function from R session and passing `pgrep` command to list processes id matching the particular name the results from the `system` call produce one extra pid vs the same `pgrep` command used directly in shell.
This is likely the problem of creating an extra process during the `system` call which is also catched by `pgrep` and returned to R session.

The question is how can I avoid this issue and find all the processes id matching to the name?

To reproduce start any process, I will use `gedit` process (ubuntu notepad app).

Running from R:

```
system("pgrep -f gedit", intern = TRUE)
# [1] "4898" "5014"
```

Running from shell:

```
pgrep -f gedit
# 4898
```

If the extra pid is always last one returned I could use `x[-length(x)]`.

Comment: Without the `-f` parameter I get just one result. Why do you need it?

Comment: @nicola Wow, so simple, I was thinking `-f` will make it more strict and didn't even check that. I use it as a helper methods [here](https://github.com/jangorecki/rbitcoind/blob/412afec1fcce4627e57b368836c2cf8e95eb22d3/R/bitcoind.R#L99). Please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired output by dropping the `-f` parameter in the call to `pgrep`. This is what I get from my PC:

```
system("pgrep gedit", intern = TRUE)
#[1] "2888"
system("pgrep -f gedit", intern = TRUE)
#[1] "2888" "5839"
```